# Opencsv map iso 8601 to java.SQL Timestamp

Tags: java, opencsv

My data is of format '2023-12-20T23:15:49.680Z'.  This looks like ISO 8601.

I need to convert this to a java.sql TimeStamp.

I tried using this and a few other formats, none of which work:
@CsvDate(value = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: String must be in JDBC format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffff] to create a java.sql.Timestamp

What is the correct format to use?

Comment: Notice that your data has a timezone (`Z`) while `java.sql.Timestamp` does not allow for a timezone.  Without more details about your code and expectations about how time is handled in your application, we really can't help.

Comment: Your error message shows that a timestamp is not being expected at all. What is expected is a `String`. So take Basil's `Instant` and turn that into a `String` of the correct formatting

Comment: Be aware too that your assertion *My data is of format '2023-12-20T23:15:49.680Z'.* implies that, in addition to your output needing to be a `String`, your *input* is also of that type, since only `String`s have formats. If your input is actually a datetime type, please say. As a quick and dirty, to satisfy your error message, `Instant::toString().replace("T", "")` would give you the correct format

Answer (score 0):

> I need to convert this to a java.sql TimeStamp

No, you don’t.

That terribly flawed class `Timestamp` was years ago **supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes** defined in JSR 310.

**Parse your ISO 8601** compliant string as a [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2023-12-20T23:15:49.680Z" ) ;
```

The `Z` on the end of your input string means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Pronounced “Zulu”. The `Instant` class has the same meaning, representing a moment with an offset of zero.

To create a `String` with  text in that ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

If you need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, **call the new conversion methods** added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( instant ) ;
```

When you receive a `java.sql.Timestamp` object, **immediately convert** to an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant() ;
```

But **avoid the legacy dae-time classes** wherever possible. They really are the bad.

You said:

> String must be in JDBC format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffff] to create a java.sql.Timestamp

No, it does not. Use `Instant` rather than `Timestamp` and all your problems go away.

> What is the correct format to use?

Always use ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time data as text.